# Find missing data passed to SQL in-clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select *  
  from Address 
 where city in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', ... )
```

How can I modify the SQL to get only the cities provided in the query that are missing in the above result?

For example: I've 100 cities in the in-clause (hard-coded) and I want to see which cities that I passed in are not in the Address table.

Comment: Do you mean the cities provided in the list in the IN clause, which are not in the Address table? How do you provide the list of cities in the IN clause - do you hard-code them (write them in by hand)? Are they stored in a table?

Comment: You mean like using `NOT IN`?

Comment: Just edited the question. Yes, the cities are hard coded. NOT IN would simply return the rows not in the list of provided cities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `union` to build table of cities and then `minus` operator.

```
select 'Dallas' as city from dual union all 
select 'Berlin' as city from dual union all 
select 'Cracow' as city from dual union all 
select 'Praha'  as city from dual  
minus
select city from address
```

Instead of union you can use predefined type `odcivarchar2list`, which shortens syntax:

```
select column_value as city 
  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('Dallas', 'Berlin', 'Cracow', 'Praha'))
minus
select city from address
```

... and instead of `minus` You can use joins or `not in` or `not exists`.

---

Test data and output of both queries:

```
create table address (id number, city varchar2(10));
insert into address values (1, 'Rome');
insert into address values (2, 'Dallas');
insert into address values (3, 'Cracow');
insert into address values (4, 'Moscow');
insert into address values (5, 'Liverpool');
insert into address values (6, 'Cracow');
insert into address values (7, 'Seoul');

CITY
------------
Berlin
Praha
```

Comment: How do you do this in Mysql?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are looking for all addresses which is not available in the given list. You can use 'not in'

```
select *  from Address where city not in
('a',
'b',
'c',
'd',
'e',
'f'
..
)
```

Comment: That query doesn't fulfill the OP's requirements - it will simply return a list of all addresses whose city is not in the provided list of cities, whereas the OP wants a list of all cities without a matching address.