# Mysql return result missing from the IN-Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return values which are not present in the IN Clause within the same table.

```
select * from tableA where columnA in ('aa', 'bb', 'cc')
```

I will get back only result which exist in that table like

```
id | columnA | columnB
----------------------
1  | aa      | text
2  | bb      | text2
```

What I am require is something like

```
id  | columnA | columnB
----------------------
null| cc      |
```

essentially record which dont exist. My question is similar to - [Find missing data passed to SQL in-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41049546), but it is for Oracle. I am looking for Mysql.

I tried something like this but it didnt work

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.columnA,
    t1.columnB
FROM
    tableA t1
    LEFT JOIN tableA t2 ON t1.columnA = t2.columnA
WHERE
    t2.columnA IS NULL
    AND t1.columnA in('aa', 'bb', 'cc')
```

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? How does the values list is inserted into the query?

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the values using a derived table and then use `left join` on that:

```
select x.a
from (select 'aa' as columnA union all
      select 'bb' as columnA union all
      select 'cc' as columnA 
     ) x left join
     tableA a
     using (columnA)
where a.columnA is null;
```

Comment: I have lot of records that I want to search inside IN-Clause, this approach will be difficult and the table has millions of records. Cant create temp table as well.

Comment: @arjun You **must** provide your values list as a rowset (or convert to) - no variants. You may provide this list as, for example, CSV list or JSON-array and parse it into the rowset in the query.

Comment: json_table could potentially be used for this purpose.